# Where can I download Marklogic v10.0-4?

Tags: marklogic

On the main download page, I don't see any option for Marklogic 10.0-4 version.

Please let me know where can I download the v10.0-4?

Comment: https://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/10.0 Are you looking specifically for 10.0-4 and not 10.0-4.2, Released June 2020?

Comment: Yes. 10.0-4 particular

Answer (score 2):

[MarkLogic Support](https://help.marklogic.com) can provide older versions of MarkLogic Server.  Just open a ticket, and specify which version and platform you need.